# Service Fabric App Deployment Not Creating Service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I deploy my service fabric app to my local cluster via Visual Studio 2017, my service is **not** getting **created**.  I have to manually go into the `Service Fabric Explorer` and **click create**.  Why?

[image: cluster management screenshot]

---

**Background:** I did some project re-naming and moving folders around.  I think that broke this as it used to work.

---

**Output Window** of Service Fabric Tools

```
Started executing script 'Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication'.
[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationPackagePath 'C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\The Repo\TheProject.IdentityDomain\TheProject.Identity.App\pkg\Debug' -ApplicationParameterFilePath 'C:\Users\mdepouw\source\repos\The Repo\TheProject.IdentityDomain\TheProject.Identity.App\PublishProfiles\..\ApplicationParameters\Local.5Node.xml' -ApplicationParameter @{_WFDebugParams_='[{"""CodePackageName""":"""Code""","""CodePackageLinkFolder""":null,"""ConfigPackageName""":null,"""ConfigPackageLinkFolder""":null,"""DataPackageName""":null,"""DataPackageLinkFolder""":null,"""LockFile""":null,"""WorkingFolder""":null,"""ServiceManifestName""":"""IdentityServicePkg""","""EntryPointType""":"""Main""","""DebugExePath""":"""C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\Packages\\Debugger\\VsDebugLaunchNotify.exe""","""DebugArguments""":""" {83288f71-0cb5-49bc-b56b-f212d6fc8486} -p [ProcessId] -tid [ThreadId]""","""DebugParametersFile""":null}]'} -Action Create -SkipPackageValidation:$true -ErrorAction Stop
Creating application...


ApplicationName        : fabric:/IdentityApp
ApplicationTypeName    : IdentityAppType
ApplicationTypeVersion : 1.0.0
ApplicationParameters  : { "_WFDebugParams_" = "[{"CodePackageName":"Code","CodePackageLinkFolder":null,"ConfigPackageN
                         ame":null,"ConfigPackageLinkFolder":null,"DataPackageName":null,"DataPackageLinkFolder":null,"
                         LockFile":null,"WorkingFolder":null,"ServiceManifestName":"IdentityServicePkg","EntryPointType
                         ":"Main","DebugExePath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\C
                         ommon7\\Packages\\Debugger\\VsDebugLaunchNotify.exe","DebugArguments":" 
                         {83288f71-0cb5-49bc-b56b-f212d6fc8486} -p [ProcessId] -tid 
                         [ThreadId]","DebugParametersFile":null}]" }

Create application succeeded.


Finished executing script 'Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:07.2779519
Started executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus -ApplicationName 'fabric:/IdentityApp' -ErrorAction Stop
The application has started.
Service Status:

The application is ready.
Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:04.7490158
Launching the browser with URL https://localhost:44300/ to open the application.Started executing script 'Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication'.
[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName 'fabric:/IdentityApp' -ErrorAction Stop
Removing application...
Remove application instance succeeded
Finished executing script 'Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:08.9813491
Started executing script 'UnregisterApplicationType'.
[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; if (Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName 'IdentityAppType' | Where-Object { $_.ApplicationTypeVersion -eq '1.0.0' }) { Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName 'IdentityAppType' -ApplicationTypeVersion '1.0.0' -ErrorAction Stop -Force }
Unregister application type succeeded.
Finished executing script 'UnregisterApplicationType'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:07.9996788
Launching the browser with URL https://localhost:44300/ to open the application.
```

Comment: Can you check the output window in VS as you deploy? You'll see the powershell commands fly by, and likely an error.

Comment: I almost posted that. I didn't see anything.  Let me update my question.  @LoekD

Comment: @LoekD I've added the output window to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ApplicationManifest.xml` I had to define the `<DefaultServices>` I wanted:

```xml
<DefaultServices>
    <!-- The section below creates instances of service types, when an instance of this 
         application type is created. You can also create one or more instances of service type using the 
         ServiceFabric PowerShell module.

         The attribute ServiceTypeName below must match the name defined in the imported ServiceManifest.xml file. -->
    <Service Name="Identity">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="IdentityService" InstanceCount="[Identity_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
</DefaultServices>
```